# SQL Query - Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have something like this:

```
USERS (ID, name);
SESSIONS (ID, userID, date)
```

Now, I need to get all users which have at least 3 sessions and at least one of those sessions is in 2015.

```
SELECT must have USERS.*, lastSessionDate and sessionCount
```

I am using microsoft sql server, any help would be appreciated.

EDIT (what I have so far):

```
SELECT ID, name,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM SESSIONS 
    WHERE SESSIONS.userID = ID
    AND ((SELECT MAX(date)
        FROM SESSIONS 
        WHERE SESSIONS.userID = ID) > '2014-12-31')) AS sessionCount
FROM USERS
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM SESSIONS
    WHERE SESSIONS.userID = ID
    AND ((SELECT MAX(date)
        FROM SESSIONS
        WHERE SESSIONS.userID = ID) > '2014-12-31')) > 2
/*
GROUP BY ID, name
HAVING (SELECT MAX(date)
        FROM SESSIONS
        WHERE SESSIONS.userID = ID) > '2014-12-31'
*/
ORDER BY sessionCount DESC
```

Comment: Have you tried anything before you asked? Would be groovy to post your code, if you did

Comment: @Veljko89 - I added it in "EDIT"

Comment: @jarlh - no, it is a job and I have much more complicated tables but I have simplified them for the thing that I am missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here all columns you need:

```
WITH cte
as
(
    SELECT userId, count(*) as c, MAX(date) as lastDate
        FROM SESSIONS
        WHERE userId IN (SELECT userId FROM SESSIONS WHERE DATEPART(year, date) = 2015) -- filter 2015 year
        GROUP BY s.userId
        HAVING count(*) > 2 -- filter at least 3 sessions
)
SELECT u.*, cte.c as sessionCount, cte.lastDate as lastSessionDate
    FROM USERS u
    INNER JOIN cte on u.Id = cte.userId;
```

Comment: Wouldn't this take only those who have at least three sessions in 2015?

Comment: No, `at least one of those sessions is in 2015`

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Thanks!

Comment: One more question. How would I update USERS table in this case? If under WITH cte as (...) I put UPDATE instad of SELECT and not use 'cte' or 'sessions' tables at all in UPDATE part of the query, should it work?

Comment: ... something like: UPDATE USERS SET someOtherUsersColumn= 'XY'

Comment: `WITH cte
as 
(...)
UPDATE u
SET someOtherUsersColumn= 'XY'
FROM USERS u
INNER JOIN cte on u.Id = cte.userId;`

Comment: nevermind, I got it. For anyone who would need this, UPDATE query would be:
  UPDATE USERS
SET someOtherUsersColumn= 'XY'
WHERE ID IN (
SELECT USERS.ID FROM USERS INNER JOIN cte on USERS.ID = cte.userID)

Comment: No need for `SELECT DISTINCT` in that innermost sub-query.

Answer (score 1):

Have a derived table where you count sessions and 2015 sessions for each userid. Join users table with that table:

```
select u.ID, u.name
from users u
join (select id, count(*) as cnt, sum(case when YEAR(date) = 2015 then 1 end) as cnt2015
      from sessions
      group by id) s on u.id = s.id
where s.cnt >= 3 and s.cnt2015 >= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not the nicest solution but you could do something like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    users
WHERE 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM sessions 
        WHERE sessions.userID=users.ID
    )>3
AND 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM sessions 
        WHERE sessions.userID=users.ID 
        AND YEAR(sessions.date)=2015
    )>=1
```

A much nicer solution would be something like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    users
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            sessions.userID,
            COUNT(*) AS nbrOf,
            SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(sessions.date)=2015 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS nbrOfYear
        FROM 
            sessions
        GROUP BY
            sessions.userID
    ) as tbl
    ON users.id=tbl.userID
    AND tbl.nbrOf>3
    AND tbl.nbrOfYear>=1
```

Comment: `>=` instead of `=>`

Comment: @RuslanK. : Update the answer

Comment: 'sessions.userID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Adder : Update the anwser

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  u.ID,
  u.name, 
  MAX(Date) lastsessiondate
FROM 
  USERS u
JOIN
  [SESSIONS] s
ON 
  u.ID = s.userID
GROUP BY 
  u.ID, u.name
HAVING 
  COUNT(*) > 2
  and MAX(CASE WHEN Date>= '2016-01-01' THEN '2014-01-01' ELSE Date END) >= '2015-01-01'
```